# How to transfer data from GCS to Colab GCE VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I just launched a Colab virtual machine on the google cloud platform, following this little guide: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html

I can connect to the VM with Colab or ssh into the machine and use the shell. Everything seems to be working fine.

Now I want to transfer data from google cloud storage to the VM and have it accessible from the Colab connection. This is easiest from the shell, but I can't figure out where the Colab notebook lives on the disk... Poking around the filesystem from the notebook and from the shell, I can't find where they meet.

Where on the VM should I transfer data to make it easily accessible from the notebook?

Comment: tried to replicate the Colab GCE VM by following the steps from [starting a GCE VM on Colab via GCP Marketplace](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html) I found that the Colab Notebooks is not inside the disk of the VM, but it's being created on the google drive. On this article [How to Deal With Files in Google Colab](https://neptune.ai/blog/google-colab-dealing-with-files) it is stated that "Since a Colab notebook is hosted on Google’s cloud servers, there’s no direct access to files on your local drive or any other environment by default."

Answer (score 1):

Replicated the Colab GCE VM on my end by following the steps from this documentation [starting a GCE VM on Colab via GCP Marketplace](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html). After the creation of Colab GCE VM found that Colab Notebooks was not inside the filesystem/disk of VM, but it's created on Google Drive. From this article [How to Deal With Files in Google Colab](https://neptune.ai/blog/google-colab-dealing-with-files) it is stated that *"Since a Colab Notebook is hosted on Google’s Cloud servers, there’s no direct access to files on your local drive or any other environment by default."*